# What will happen when a laser which carries information passes through a glass?

Tags: laser

I am currently working on my summer project. One of my tasks is to figure out what will happen when a laser which carries information passes through a glass, like how will the glass affect the laser(e.g. the pass loss). I am trying to find some research paper, but still not get enough information about that. Can anybody introduce me some books or research paper related to that?

Comment: A good place to start is [The RP Photonics Encyclopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html). For example, here is the article on [Absorption](https://www.rp-photonics.com/absorption.html)

Comment: We send light through glass optical fibers for telecommunications. There is a lot of physics in engineering understanding the different types of dispersion which limits how closely you can space the  pulses of light. look up dispersion, material dispersion mode dispersion, waveguide dispersion, single mode and multimode fiber. Try to understand why different glasses has different indexes of refraction too.

Comment: For absorption, take a look at the history of fiber optic communications and how they purified the glass.

Comment: The early history of fiber optics, up to 1980 or so, is all about figuring out how to reduce the absorption of glass so you can send a signal through what is in effect a several kilometer thick piece of it.

Comment: Google Charles Kao for one of the key researchers in the field.